# Matching json formatted text file using regular expression

Tags: python, json, regex, file

I wish to do matching of json formatted text file using regular expression. I have tried:

```
data = []
location = '.'

                        print(line)
```

Data is in a text file (abc.txt)
Please not there are 10 files like this and I've to iterate through each line of each file
I have to write a regular expression to match this text data and extract it

Data:

Comment: Why do you need to use a regex? Since the data is already formatted as JSON, it would be a lot easier to parse the json and then access the key/value pairs.

Comment: I want to try it with regex, please let me know if its possible

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regex to parse JSON. That does not make sense.

Use a json parser such as described here https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html or here https://realpython.com/python-json/

Comment: But that's actually a text file, it will be easier with json parser but is there a method for regex as well?

Comment: There is no "method". The "method" you need is to learn enough regex and look closely at the json structure of your files, and write the regex that can parse that. In any normal situation this is a lot more work and a lot more time consuming than using a json parser. Json is well defined and well structured, and all the hard work is already done for you. With regex, you have to do all that hard work and reinvent the wheel. And it will not be reusable for other cases or other files. If you insist on doing it, all you need is any guide to regex and start trying.